# Index 2 out of bounds for length 2

Tags: java

why it is giving error after 3rd input??

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Baloon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int row = sc.nextInt();
        int col = sc.nextInt();
        int[][] arr  = new int[row][col];
        for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; i<col; j++) { 
                arr[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by a relatively simple typo in your code, second nested loop should compare `j<col` not `i<col`.

```
for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<col; j++) { 
        arr[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
    }
}
```